# What do these sentences mean? And why are there no verbs at the end?

Tags: translation, verbs, song-lyrics

To be more specific, they have no verb at the end so it kinda seems incomplete. Also, I do know that verbs can modify nouns when placed before them.

> 自分を世界さえも変えてしまえそうな瞬間は何時も直ぐそばに。

and the second one is

> 心を吹き抜ける空の色香る風。

Comment: got any context?

Answer (score 3):

When I checked the given phrases on the Internet, [here](http://www.kasi-time.com/item-1.html) I found out that they were parts of the lyrics titled COLORS.

> (1) 自分を世界さえも変えてしまえそうな瞬間は何時も直ぐそばに。

If you write (1) according to the lyrics, it is actually (2).
(2) has some words omitted, and if I supplement it/them, (2) will probably become (3).

(3) implies (4), so the meaning of (1) is like (4).

- (2) 自分を 世界さえも 変えてしまえそうな 瞬間は いつもすぐそばに・・・
- (3) 自分を 世界さえも 変えてしまえそうな 瞬間は いつもすぐそばに**ある**
- (4) 自分を変えてしまえそうな瞬間はいつもそばにある。 もっと言｛い｝えば、世界さえも変えてしまえそうな(とても大きな力を持った)瞬間はいつもそばにある。*The moment that could change myself is always by my side. To put it more, the (enormousely powerful) moment that could even change the world is always by my side.*

> (5) 心を吹き抜ける空の色香る風。

(5) is written as the last line with (9) in (6)-(9) of the last part of this lyrics.

> (6) 自分を 世界さえも 変えてしまえそうな
>   (7) 瞬間を 感じる今ここに・・・
>   (8) 光へと 両手を伸ばして・・・
>
> (9) 心を吹き抜ける 空の色 香る風

The phrase composition of (6) and (7) combined is similar to (2), but in (7) no word is  omitted but a method of inversion is used, and in ordinary expression, the phrase with (6) and (7) becomes (10) .

- (10) 自分を 世界さえも 変えてしまえそうな 瞬間を 今ここに**感じる**

The 感じる is a very important word and it is the keyword to understand the meaning of (5) or (9).

The interpretation of (5) is (11) or (12).
(12) sounds more natural than (11).

- (11) 光へと 両手を伸ばして 感じる 心を吹き抜ける 空の色 香る風
- (12) 光へと 両手を伸ばして 私は 心を吹き抜ける 空の色を感じる そして 香る風を 感じる
  *By extending both hands to the light, I feel the color of the sky blowing through my heart and I feel a fragrant wind.*